# Problems using pickle to create a save/load function for my game (Python)

Tags: python, load, save, pickle

I'm trying to use pickle to create a save/load function for my first basic game but I'm getting an error.

My code is

```
def load():
    with open('save_game.dat', 'wb') as f:
        player_money,weed = pickle.load
```

and my trace back is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 301, in runcode
File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Jake\Pictures\Documents\Blue Coat\Compooting\Weed Game.py", line 23, in load
player_money,weed = pickle.load
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

I changed the code to include (f) but I'm still getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 301, in runcode
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Jake\Pictures\Documents\Blue Coat\Compooting\Weed Game.py", line 23, in load
    player_money,weed = pickle.load(f)
io.UnsupportedOperation: read
```

Comment: `pickle.load(f)` missing parentheses & argument

Comment: Ah thank you, didn't notice that

Comment: you are reading from the file, change the param to `rb` instead of `wb`

Comment: Okay thanks, I copied it from another answer so I have no idea what that means

Comment: `r` means read, `w` means write, `b` means binary, see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) for details

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Python [documentation on file modes](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) -- In your code, 'wb' should instead be 'rb'.